# PHP deprecated functions will make performance issues?

Tags: php, version, deprecated

I have updated PHP version to 5.3 but My web application was developed based on PHP 4 so now I'm getting error warnings about some functions has deprecated eg: ereg.

My Question is, deprecated function will make performance issue?

Comment: they will most likely cause performance issues when they stop working if you continue to keep the engine updated and not the code. for now, you should be safe.

Comment: Heads up. PHP 5.3 will also be EOL next year :-)

Comment: In short : No, not at all.

Comment: Well if you imagine that everytime you run into one of these errors it has to output the error and record it in the error_logs then yes there will be performance issues as completing 1 step successfully is better than having to perform 2-3 extra processes.

Comment: No. However, if you'd like to take a cautious approach and change it, the recommended replacement is [`preg_match`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: @castis, "_they will most likely cause performance issues when they stop working_" ehh..? They will never stop working. How should that happend? But if he *upgrade* in the future, lets say in ten years, then _some_ of the deprecated functions _may_ have been removed for good.

Comment: @davidkonrad _"...if you continue to keep the engine updated and not the code."_ I think he was meaning when the OP upgrades to 5.4 or 5.5.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104632/updating-to-php-5-3-with-deprecated-functions-warning-disabled as some of those warnings may indicate problems needing attention.  There is a link to additional resources in the answer.  For instance see this incompatibility guide http://us2.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php

Comment: Then it is a llame comment, isnt it? It will not cause performance, not now or in the future, *unless* he upgrades again. Right? Do I need to take a raincoat on? Yes - it is not raining, and will not rain for days the whetherforecast tells - but if you go out in 14 days, and it rains, you should wear a raincoat - so take a raincoat on now.

Comment: @davidkonrad considering PHP 4 was *discontinued* 8 years ago, I'm assuming the code base won't be updated any time soon if they havn't already shown initiative. The code works now, but in another 8 years when OP updates to another engine version without updating the code...

Comment: expectations and requirements of your script will also play a role in this. If you are loading a fairly simple page you could benchmark the use of deprecated and current functions and see that while technically there may be a performance difference between the two it will be so negligible that you might as well say there is no performance loss. Matter of opinion. So long as the site isn't slow and crappy then the matter here is more of standards than the actual performance of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, in case that the deprecated notices are turned off in php.ini

But the problem is not with speed. The existence of ereg function will not be guaranteed in the future versions of PHP.

So you should use another regular expression function ([PCRE](http://php.net/pcre)).

BTW, you should keep in mind that **ereg** and **preg_match** regular expressions syntax are not the same.